# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, arrays, return

I have this idea of an multiarray with my files sorted into different groups/arrays.
Thinking it would be the easiest and most clean way to check what file we're inside, and should the navigation state be set to active on navigation tab 1,2 or 3?

I have this array;

```
Array
(
[home] => Array
    (
        [0] => index.php
        [1] => something.php
    )

[tour] => Array
    (
        [0] => tour.php
    )

[tutorials] => Array
    (
        [0] => tutorials.php
    )
)
```

The idea is, if i click on the home navigation button it goes to the index.php and a function checks whether it's the Home button that needs the active state, or the Tour button. In this case its the Home button.

```
[home] => Array
    (
        [0] => index.php
```

I made this function

```
function findNavigationActive($tap, $filename) {
    if(in_array($filename, $topNavigationPages[$tap])) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

it should check, if index.php ($filename) is in the Home ($tap) array or navi-tap, then return 1. Unfortunately i get this error insted;

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /project/../../topNavigationHandler.php on line 21

What am I doing wrong?

**FIXED**

Used global $topNavigationPages; outside the function, and set $topNavigationPages values (array) beneath, and again used global $topNavigationPages inside the function to pull the array inside.
Thanks @tombs !

Comment: variable scope issue, $topNavigationPages is not defined in, or passed to the function

Comment: whats the value of $tap and $topNavigationPages

Comment: How do I solve that?
- @jdog : $tap should be either home, tour or tutorials and $topNavigationPages is the larger array.

Comment: parse the array like you pares the other varariables, `function findNavigationActive($tap, $filename,$topNavigationPages) {` or even better  `function findNavigationActive( $filename,$topNavigationPages[$tap]) {`

Comment: What if I'd like to use this function on other pages without having to copy the $topNavigationPages to every page?

Comment: well $topNavigationPages will have to exist somewhere the  other functions are called. no magic in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this error means is that the second parameter isn't an array, therefore you can try something like this.:

```
if (is_array($topNavigationPages[$tap])) {
    if(in_array($filename, $topNavigationPages[$tap])) {
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

You can do this without nesting the if loops by using a strict and operator.

Hope this helps

Note: 
To resolve your scope issue you can use either a global value or a constant. To use a constant use the 'define' function, for a global declare the variable as such at the beginning of your file and in every subsequent function that you use it in. I strongly recommend using a constant.

Comment: I noticed after posting and made a few edits. I addressed the scope issue and the potential error of $tap not being an array, is there anything I missed?

Comment: I've added
global $topNavigationPages;
$topNavigationPages = array(...);

And when i check with
if(findNavigationActive("home", "index.php")) {
 echo "1";
} else {
 echo "0";
}

it returns 0.

Comment: You'd need to first declare your array as global outside of your function and then again inside of your function when you're calling on it. The alternative is define it as a constant outside of your functions using define('NAV_ARRAY', $topNavigationPages, True); and then replace $topNavigationPages by NAV_ARRAY inside of your function (without declaring anything as global)

Comment: Had no idea that i needed to use global outside and inside the function. Thank you very much, it works like a charm now!

Comment: highly recommended NOT to use global.